# cannot get the parent property this property when I have two inner loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a complicated scenario which I am really confused how to deal with it.
I have an array as follows:

```
stories=[
    {
        "categ": "politics",
        "arr": [{
            "t": 1
        }, {
            "t": 2
        }, {
            "t": 3
        }]
    }, 
    {
        "categ": "Business",
        "arr": [{
            "t": 1
        }, {
            "t": 2
        }, {
            "t": 3
        }]
    }
]
```

As you can see this array has another array inside it and depending on what is executed I need to loop through the first array and find the appropriate array inside the first array. So for instance if I want to get the array related to business category I need to loop through the first array and choose the array related to business. To do so I have the following code:

```
<div className="row">
                {
                    this.props.stories.map((item,i)=> <Story key={i}   position={i} story={item} ></Story>)

                }
            </div>
```

So you can see that with map I am able to loop through the first array. Now considering that by using `this.props.categ` I can access the category that I want. so I have to change my code to sth like below:

```
 <div className="row" >
                {

                 this.props.stories.map(function(snippet){
                     if(snippet.categ==="politics"){
                     return(
                         snippet.arr.map((item,i)=> <Story key={i} position={i} story={item} ></Story>)


                     );

                     }
                 })
                }
            </div>
```

But in the above code "politics" is hard coded and should be replaced with this.props.categ. However as soon as I replace that I get the error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

which totally make sense since I am loosing the parent this since I do not use es6 fat arrow. Now how can make this work?

Comment: `I have an array as follows` it is invalid syntax, so you have nothing

Comment: Sorry I will fix my arry

Comment: @JaromandaX in my real project I am using the right array but I wanted to  make it simple so put the above array as an example

Comment: @JaromandaX it is fixed now and the array is in a right format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the outer map function like

```
 <div className="row" >
            {

             this.props.stories.map(function(snippet){
                 if(snippet.categ===this.props.categ){
                 return(
                     {snippet.arr.map((item,i)=> <Story key={i} position={i} story={item} ></Story>})


                 );

                 }
             }.bind(this))
            }
        </div>
```

This will allow you map function to refer to the outer context where `prop` is available. Also you forgot to include your inner map function inside `{}`

Other option is to use the arrow function

```
 <div className="row" >
            {

             this.props.stories.map(snippet) => {
                 if(snippet.categ===this.props.categ){
                 return(
                     {snippet.arr.map((item,i)=> <Story key={i} position={i} story={item} ></Story>})


                 );

                 }
             }.bind(this))
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks but when I do that I get this error: bundle.js:41014 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.stories.map(...).bind is not a function

Comment: It should work. The other way is to use the arrow function

Comment: Check the update. You forgot , `{}` for the iner map function

Comment: Does it affect the speed? after doing so my appliaction is very slow?

Comment: No it doesn't affect the speed, The problem may lie elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Save the `this` to `that` before entering the function.

Then use `that.props.categ` to refer to the outer `this`.

If that makes any sense :D

Something like so:

```
render(){
    // place here
    // at the top of render function
    // but outside the return
    var that = this;

    return (
        {something.map(function(snippet){
           if (snippet.categ === that.props.categ){
               // do things here
           }
        })}
    );

}
```

Comment: thanks I tried that but it is not possible in my scenario since I am in the render when I do the above I get compilation error

Comment: pls update your answer to include more of your render function and i'm sure i can help :D